# Why does postfix send mails with wrong ip address?

Tags: postfix

I have a multi domain setup on my virtual server:

master.cf:

```
127.0.0.1:smtp inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix-localhost
      -o smtp_helo_name=localhost
      -o smtp_bind_address=127.0.0.1
      -o myhostname=localhost
      -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=100
      -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/the-grue.de-0001/privkey.pem
      -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/the-grue.de-0001/fullchain.pem

95.129.55.226:smtp inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.the-grue.de
      -o smtp_helo_name=mail.the-grue.de
      -o smtp_bind_address=95.129.55.226
      -o myhostname=mail.the-grue.de
      -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=100
      -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/the-grue.de-0001/privkey.pem
      -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/the-grue.de-0001/fullchain.pem

95.129.55.232:smtp inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.maennerchor-kirchseeon.de
      -o smtp_helo_name=mail.maennerchor-kirchseeon.de
      -o smtp_bind_address=95.129.55.232
      -o myhostname=mail.maennerchor-kirchseeon.de
      -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=100
      -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/maennerchor-kirchseeon.de-0001/privkey.pem
      -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/maennerchor-kirchseeon.de-0001/fullchain.pem

95.129.55.223:smtp inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.goldschmiede-grunwald.de
      -o smtp_helo_name=mail.goldschmiede-grunwald.de
      -o smtp_bind_address=95.129.55.223
      -o myhostname=mail.goldschmiede-grunwald.de
      -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=100
      -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/goldschmiede-grunwald.de/privkey.pem
      -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/goldschmiede-grunwald.de/fullchain.pem

the-grue-out  unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=95.129.55.226
   -o smtp_helo_name=mail.the-grue.de
   -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.the-grue.de

maennerchor-kirchseeon-out  unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=95.129.55.232
   -o smtp_helo_name=mail.maennerchor-kirchseeon.de
   -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.maennerchor-kirchseeon.de

goldschmiede-grunwald-out  unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=95.129.55.223
   -o smtp_helo_name=mail.goldschmiede-grunwald.de
   -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.goldschmiede-grunwald.de
```

This works very well, in general. But I have some virtual aliases defined:

virtual_alias:

```
s@maennerchor-kirchseeon.de               a@b.de, c@d.de
```

If someone sends an E-Mail to `s@maennerchor-kirchseeon.de`, it sometimes comes from 95.129.55.232, but sometimes from 95.129.55.226. In the latter case, it is of course considered as spam.

Edit: I have this in main.cf:

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport
```

and that's the content of `/etc/postfix/sender_transport`:

```
# Use source IP - 95.129.55.226
@the-grue.de                the-grue-out:

# Use source IP -  95.129.55.232
@maennerchor-kirchseeon.de  maennerchor-kirchseeon-out:

# Use source IP -  95.129.55.223
@goldschmiede-grunwald.de goldschmiede-grunwald-out:
```

I ran `postmap /etc/postfix/sender_transport` after editing it.

What have I configured wrong? I have found many similar questions, considering domain names or single domain setups, but for my use case, I didn't find anything.

Comment: Do you have sender_dependent_default_transport_maps defined? Look here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170905/postfix-virtual-domain-on-specific-ip-address

Comment: @kab00m: yes, I have. I'll update the question.

Comment: So, you want an email sent to @maennerchor-kirchseeon.de to be routed to external domains through maennerchor-kirchseeon.de-out ? In this case alias address do not mean anything, output will be selected on real sender address, alias will not be mentioned anywhere. What addresses these emails are sent from?